# Difference between Balance and Broadcast fan out in Akka Streams

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a little confusion with fan out strategies in `Akka streams`, I read that 
`Broadcast` – (1 input, N outputs) given an input element emits to each output, while `Balance` – (1 input, N outputs) given an input element emits to one of its output ports.

Can you explain me:

1. How balance does work with multiple consumers?
2. Meaning of phrase "emits to one of its output ports"
3. Does port is same to downstream?
4. Does 'Balance' stand for replication of input stream into a few output partition
5. What does "balance is enabling graphs to be split apart and multiple instances of downstream subscribers replicated to handle the volume" mean?

Comment: Broadcast simply takes a message and sends it to every output port it has.  Balance takes a message and only sends it to one of the outputs based on availability and back pressure of that output port.

Comment: @ Brian Pendleton  but what if I have two downstream consumers simultaneously like this (Z <~ D,  F <~ D) where D is builder.add(Balance[T](2))?

Comment: Either `Z` or `F` will get the message.  Not both of them.  If you want both of them to process every message, use `Broadcast`.  `Balance` is used when `Z` and `F` are likely identical processing steps, but you just want to split the work across multiple actors.  Look here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11/scala/stream/stream-cookbook.html#Balancing_jobs_to_a_fixed_pool_of_workers

Comment: @ Brian Pendleton when I write builder.add(Balance[T](2)), both of them receive the data (I checked it several times). In this case, 2 means a `outputPorts` but not actor count for `Balance`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation...  broadcast emits (sends) the element to every consumer.  balance only emits to the first available consumer.

[broadcast](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#broadcast)

> Emit each incoming element each of n outputs.

[balance](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#balance)

> Fan-out the stream to several streams. Each upstream element is
>   emitted to the first available downstream consumer.

EDIT from comments:

From your gist, you should make two averageCarrierDelay functions, one for each `Z` and `F`.  Then you can see all the elements sent to each.

```
val averageCarrierDelayZ =
    Flow[FlightDelayRecord]
      .groupBy(30, _.uniqueCarrier)
        .fold(("", 0, 0)){
          (x: (String, Int, Int), y:FlightDelayRecord) => {
            println(s"Z Received Element: ${y}")
            val count = x._2 + 1
            val totalMins = x._3 + Try(y.arrDelayMins.toInt).getOrElse(0)
            (y.uniqueCarrier, count, totalMins)
          }
        }.mergeSubstreams


val averageCarrierDelayF =
    Flow[FlightDelayRecord]
      .groupBy(30, _.uniqueCarrier)
        .fold(("", 0, 0)){
          (x: (String, Int, Int), y:FlightDelayRecord) => {
            println(s"F Received Element: ${y}")
            val count = x._2 + 1
            val totalMins = x._3 + Try(y.arrDelayMins.toInt).getOrElse(0)
            (y.uniqueCarrier, count, totalMins)
          }
        }.mergeSubstreams
```

Edit 2: To check things in the future I'd recommend a generic logger for stream stages so you can see what is going on.

```
def logElement[A](msg: String) = Flow[A].map { a => println(s"${msg} ${a}"); a }
```

Doing this allows you to do something like:

```
D ~> logElement[FlightDelayRecord]("F received: ") ~> F
D ~> logElement[FlightDelayRecord]("Z received: ") ~> Z
```

This way you can check areas of your graph for strange behavior that you may or may not be expecting.

Comment: I have a graph like this (Z <~ D, F <~ D) where D is builder.add(Balance[T](2)), in this situation D send values both to Z and F. According to your answer, D must send only to one of them, or my thinking is wrong?

Comment: Can you please post your entire code file?  If what you say is true, then Akka has a bug in it.  Balance should only send it to the first available consumer.

Comment: it's https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4515afdd9c40709b23a19e55beb76b3e  my entire code file, the code was modified from a tutorial. In this code val D send `Balance` to Z and F, and both of them receive data and print result to console with diff formating. Maybe, my insight of situation is wrong, in this case, please clarify me my mistake.

Comment: Both of them will receive data.  Just not the same elements.  It looks like you're aggregating things, so some of you're elements are going to Z and some are going to F.  You should log the individual elements going to each Sink instead of summations.  That will show you how the framework is balancing the load.

Comment: I launched the app a few time, both of them received the same data (in method which made computation), and me as result, in the terminal i see the same result, but with different format

Comment: I updated the answer with something you should try to see each element.  Make 2 aggregators, one for Z and one for F.  Those will just print out what elements they recieve as they aggregate.  You should not see the same element go to both Z and F.

Comment: Was i wrong when i used the same function ` averageCarrierDelay` for both of them?

Comment: No, all I did was add a print statement for each element.  `Z` and `F` were both receiving elements, but they were never getting the same one.  I just wanted you to see that each element will only go through either Z or F, but not both.

Comment: @ Brian Pendleton thx for great clarification. As i understood, `Balance` strategy split incoming stream into a few separate, while `Broadcast` just duplicate incoming stream, is it correct insight?

Comment: Broadcast duplicates elements.  Balance picks a single path for each element, based on load of each path.

Comment: In this article https://medium.com/@kvnwbbr/diving-into-akka-streams-2770b3aeabb0#.x6f3vfxcc  there is picture, it shows that `Balance` split incoming to separated outputs

Comment: Yes. From that article, it says what we've all been saying here. Balance signals one of its output ports for any given signal, but not both. According to the documentation, “each upstream element is emitted to the first available downstream consumer”. This means events are not distributed in a deterministic fashion, with one output being signalled and then the other, but rather whichever downstream subscriber happens to be available.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already said, broadcast emits its input to *all* output ports, while balance emits its input to *one* output port based on backpressure.

When you use `GraphStage`, you need to choose which output port you want to use. Consider this example:

```
val q1 = Source.queue[Int](10, OverflowStrategy.fail)
val q2 = Source.queue[Int](10, OverflowStrategy.fail)
GraphDSL.create(q1, q2)(Keep.both) { implicit b => (input1, input2) =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  val balance = b.add(Balance[Int](2))

  val consumer1, consumer2, consumer3, consumer4 = b.add(Sink.foreach[Int](println))

  input1 ~> broadcast.in
  input2 ~> balance.in

  broadcast.out(0) ~> consumer1
  broadcast.out(1) ~> consumer2

  balance.out(0) ~> consumer3
  balance.out(1) ~> consumer4

  ClosedShape
}
```

Here we connect one input to a broadcast stage and one to a balance stage. Then we connect different output ports of the broadcast and balance stages to the respective consumers.

In this particular case, when you run the stream, elements coming through the first input will be passed to both `consumer1` and `consumer2`, because a broadcast stage copies its input to all its outputs (and here are two outputs), and elements coming through the second input will be distributed evenly across `consumer3` and `consumer4` based on the speed of your terminal (i.e. the speed of `println`), because `Sink.foreach` backpressures when its function executes for long time.

Note the we have specified that the broadcast and balance stages have 2 ports each (when calling their factory methods), and that we have specified which output port we connect to which consumer.